# how to create a view that shows blogs count for a user?

Tags: views, 6

I want to create a view that list out the following fields

1. User name
2. User email
3. Discussion count
4. Blog count

I created the view and add the User: Name and User: Email in the fields but it shows me the duplicate users and Also I have no idea about how to add the discussion count and blog count to the view.

I have created the view of node type.
Any help?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what that "blog count" should exist of? Is that the number of blog-posts a user made? And if, so, what is considered a "blog-post"?

Comment: Yes it is the the number of the blog posts a user made.

Comment: And "Blog posts" are that nodes of type "blog"?

Comment: yes thay are of type "blog".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at answering this. Create a view where:

Under Fields you select the User name, email and User:Uid. Then add a custom field.
Under the custom field write a query in Value:

```
<?php $result = db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM node where uid='%s' and type='blog'",$data->users_uid)); 
echo $result;
?>
```

This query find the number of posts written by each user.

Under filters choose Node:type = 'content type used to store profiles'
(as you want to count the number of blogs of every user who has a profile).